# How can i use the Check Boxes with ListView and Insert the value in Sqlite Database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-assets

I have created one database with three table and place that database into the asset folder. Now I want to show the value from one column on a list view with checkboxes and then on user selection want to insert them into the another table. SO how can I do that.

Till now what I have done is to fetch the data and show on the list. But how can I place the checkboxes and then fetch the value I don't know. The code I used is below

1.Main Activity

```
package com.example;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Cursor employees;
    private MyDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        employees = db.getEmployees(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                employees, 
                new String[] {"FullName"}, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        employees.close();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

2.Mydatabase.java

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
        //setForcedUpgradeVersion(2);
    }

    public Cursor getEmployees() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "FullName"}; 
        String sqlTables = "Employees";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }

}
```

Please suggest me that how can I do this.. Any help must be appreciated

Comment: are u facing problem in adding checkboxes to listview ???

Comment: Like I have used the list adapter and then how can I use the checkboxes inside it and also then I want to insert that selected value into the another table. I am new so don't know much sorry if my question is stupid @Goofy

Comment: so u want check boxes in the listview... right?

Comment: Yes I want to and then I want to insert that selected values in the table @Goofy

Comment: You can refer this link for checkboxes in listview http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my point of view you should create a custom adapter for the `ListView` and manually iterate over the result dataset, update an `ArrayList<MyObject>`(that you should also create).

Then create some functions in your custom adapter in order to obtain the "selected" items, or create some functions like `public void setSelected(int position)` that changes the checkbox accordingly and `private boolean isSelected(int position)` which returns whether the checkbox is selected or not.

First of all we need the object class in order to hold the dataset:

```
  class MyObject {
      //properties with setters and getters
      boolean selected;
  }
```

In Activity:

```
private MyActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  ArrayList<MyObject> data = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
  ...
  //get dataset
  for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++) {
     //create and set MyObject
     data.add(MyObject); 
  }     
  ...
  CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(..., data);
  listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
  ...
}
```

In CustomAdapter class:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   ArrayList<MyObject> data;
   //constructor, properties, getters, setters
   //implement methods

   public void setSelected(int position) {
      data.get(position).setSelected(true); //boolean selected property defines whether the checkbox is selected or not
      notifyDatasetChanged(); //update the UI
   }

   @Override
   getView() {
      CheckBox checkBox; //the check box of the list row
      ...
      if(data.get(position).isSelected()) {
         checkBox.setSelected(true);
      } else {
         checkBox.setSelected(false);
      } //update the checkbox accordingly
   }
}
```

I am writing them down very briefly to give you an overview. There are a lot of code to write but I am giving you the "hot piece".

Comment: added code to my answer. I guess this would help you understand but this code is not for copy-paste.